# If $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a(x)f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ are $C^1$, then is $a(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $a: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $g(x) = a(x)^T f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$, i.e., both are differentiable and have continuous partial derivatives. Then, **can we conclude that the function $a$ is continuous?**

---

For the scalar case $n = 1$, when $f(x) \neq 0$, we have $a(x) = g(x)/f(x)$, and hence it is continuous and even more belongs to $C^1$ by $f$, $g \in C^1$. I want to see the general case of this when the dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary. From this point, my conjecture is that $a$ could be at least continuous (and maybe $C^1$) at every $x$ for which $f(x) \neq 0$. Please help me prove or disprove this conjecture with many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example
\begin{align}
a(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
h(x) \\
 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $h(x)$ is the heavside function. Take $f(x) = (0, x)^T$, then we see
\begin{align}
a(x)^T f(x) = 
x\in C^1(\mathbb{R}).
\end{align}
but $a(x)$ is not continuous.

Comment: I changed my question by replacing $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $a(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and stating $g$ is a real-valued function. In this case, your example also works with $a(x) = [H(x) \;\;\, 1]^T$, yielding $a(x)^T f(x) = x \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Okay. Do you need me to update my post?

Comment: @ Jacky Chong I sent an update of yours. Please check it.

Comment: Looks okay. I have approved it.